# NodeJs/WS: How to throw an error server side handled on client side?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I'm trying to throw and error server side when my websocket has more than 2 connections. I have this nice client-side `onerror` method but I'm unable to reach that part of my code. I'm using nodeJS and the package `ws` which has the smallest doc on error handling.

server.js

```
theWebSocketServer.on('connection', function connection(websocket){
    if (theWebSocketServer.clients.length >2) {
        // I want to throw the error here and pass it to onerror
        console.log('No access allowed', theWebSocketServer.clients.length)
    } else {
        console.log('happy connection', theWebSocketServer.clients.length)
    }
})
```

client.js

```
wsConnection.onerror = function(eventInfo) {
   alert("There was a connection error!");
   console.log("Socket error!", eventInfo);
}
```

How can I send an error to be handled on the client side JS?

Answer (score 2):

In the docs, I can't find any way to send *an error to the client*. Since `ws` is a smallish module for websockets, I think it can be used to send messages between server and client and if you need fancy stuff you need to implement your own protocol (the way how you *interpret* those messages).

For example, in this case it could be something like this:

**Client**

```
wsConnection.onmessage = (m) => {
    // You can define errors by checking if the event data contains 
    // something specific: such as the message starts with "Error"
    // or if the property of the object is "error" and so on.
    if (m.data.startsWith("Error")) {
      alert(m.data)
      // This will show in the popup:
      // "Error: No access allowed"
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
};

wsConnection.onerror = function(eventInfo) {
  /* Handle socket errors – e.g. internet goes down, connection is broken etc. */
}
```

**Server**:

```
theWebSocketServer.on('connection', function connection(websocket){
    if (theWebSocketServer.clients.length >2) {
        websocket.send("Error: No access allowed", err => {
           // Ensure your data was actually sent successfully and then
           // Close the connection
           websocket.close()

           // Just in case your data was not sent because
           // of an error, you may be interested so see what happened
           if (err) { return console.error(err); }
        })
        // I want to throw the error here and pass it to onerror
        console.log('No access allowed', theWebSocketServer.clients.length)
    } else {
        console.log('happy connection', theWebSocketServer.clients.length)
    }
})
```